# Predicates in Utils class should be provided as constants or as static method?

Tags: java, guava, predicate

Lately, I have been working with predicates and guava utilities. I have created a Utils.class where I store some predicates that I use in different parts of the code. Thus this issue has come up and we (me and my workmates) do not get an agreement about it.

What is the right way or "good practice way" to put a predicate in a utility class?, as a constant defining it with capital letter or in a static method?. Following, I write an example:

```
public final class Utils {

public static final Predicate<Element> IS_SPECIAL = new Predicate<Element>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Element elem) {
        return elem.special;
    }
};


public static Predicate<Element> isSpecial() {
    return new Predicate<Element>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Element elem) {
        return elem.special;
    }}
```

By the way, guava offers some predifining predicates and it provides them as a method that returns predicates, but other libreries do the same offering them as constants.

Comment: Which of these do you advocate vs your co-workers, and what are their objections?

Comment: There is very little to choose between them. The former creates just one instance, whereas the latter creates one instance per invocation. The former instance won't be GC'd, the latter instances will be, assuming no references to them is being kept. But they're such cheap objects to create (/keep around in memory) that I doubt you'd notice the difference.

Comment: If an objection is about the eager evaluation of the constant, you can always use a memoizing supplier (`Suppliers.memoize(...)`). However, would then likely want to expose the result of the supplier via the method, so that the internal implementation details (i.e. that a memoizing supplier is used) is hidden. However, the in-memory size of the supplier is likely comparable to the size of the predicate instance, so you don't gain much by evaluating lazily.

Comment: I clearly advocate for the predicate constants choice. I think it is not necessary to create several time the same object with the same functionality although the impact were minimum. My workmates advocate for the second option, they argue that the constant choice is less readable and less intuitive. Additionally, they do not like use capital letter for the predicate constants.
Thank you for your comments Andy

Comment: I would agree that it is less readable. I think that @Hoopje makes a good point, which is that the method solution allows you to change the implementation without changing the API.

Comment: @MariaMontenegro it seems you have trouble understanding the website since you switched so many times the accepted answer between all the answers. You can have only 1 accepted answer. You have full control on the one you chose. If you think that other answers are useful, you can upvote those answers once you reach 15 reputation points. You can also upvote the answer you accepted.

Comment: Note also that if you can use Java 8, you should just use inline lambdas and trust the runtime to turn them into singletons appropriately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two views to this: the API and the implementation.

About the API, the solution using a method is *much* more flexible than the others. It allows to change the implementation without caring about the code, meaning that your code is not impacted by any change you'll do hidden behind the method.

About the implementation, people usually use an enumeration. The advantage of the enumeration over a constant here are numerous:

1. It's thread-safe. If you use a singleton variable, you can still have issues with the memory if some things are badly handled. An enumeration is part of the language and the definition will force every enum constant to be loaded consistently.
2. As rinde mentions in the comments, an enum is serializable. That means that you can persist your predicates for further reference.
3. An enumeration provides a kind of sub-namespace. If you want to create several predicates, they can all be defined in the same place, making it easy to find them all.
4. Enumerations don't pollute the code with explicit subclasses and you will not see `new Predicate<Element>` every few lines. However the nature of such enums make it impossible to have the same in the compiled classes. So here, it's purely better on the source code level. Of course, that's what you want, since you actually write source code.

Here's an example of how I would do it. (Yes, I'd even rename `Utils` to `Elements`, following the recent Java tacit conventions).

```
public final class Elements {
  private static enum ElementPredicate implements Predicate<Element> {
    SPECIAL {
      @Override public boolean apply(Element e) { return e.special; }
    }
  }

  public static Predicate<Element> isSpecial() {
    return ElementPredicate.SPECIAL;
  }

  private Elements() {}
}
```

Finally, note that if you're using Java 8, you should stick to the lambda mechanism offered, as Louis Wasserman mentioned in the question comments. But since the lambas are not usable in your example, because you're not retrieving special from a method but from the field directly, this advice is, unfortunately, void. However if you had a `isSpecial()` method on `Element`, you could then write your predicates directly in your code, like this:

```
Stream<T> stream = ... ;
stream
    .filter(Element::isSpecial)
```

Comment: An additional advantage of this approach is that an `enum` is `serializable` (as described by Effective Java, Item 3).

Comment: But does this method have any advantage over `private static final Predicate<Element>`?  I mean, that gets initialized in static initialization scope just like an enum.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce `enum`s are thread-safely initialized, implicitly serializable. They also offer a kind of sub-namespace in this context. And they don't pollute the code with anonymous classes or explicit subclasses (even though the compiled result is similar to that). I wouldn't have posted this answer if I didn't think it was superior to what was currently posted.

Answer (score 7):

As noted by other answers, there is a difference between the two solutions: the static constant instantiates a single object, but this object will never be garbage collected, while the method instantiates a new object every time it is called. The difference in performance will be neglectable though: the memory footprint of the predicates will be quite small, and the garbage collector is good at collecting short-lived objects.

I would still go for the method solution because of flexibility: if required, you can refactor the method to return a (private) static variable without breaking any old code. But a public static variable stays a public static variable.

Comment: It's worth a little mentioning that another advantage of the method solution is that it's compatible with method references in Java 8+.

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably do it like this...

```
public final class Utils {    
    private static final Predicate<Element> IS_SPECIAL = new Predicate<Element>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Element elem) {
            return elem.special;
        }
    };

    public static Predicate<Element> isSpecial() {
        return IS_SPECIAL;
    }
}
```

That way you call it as a method, but doesn't instantiate the predicate each time...

Answer (score 0):

`isSpecial()` would create a new instance of the predicate every time it's called. Thus I would go with `IS_SPECIAL`.

Comment: While this is technically correct, it's still a bad answer. I'd always suggest using a method, since that leaves you the freedom of changing the implementation without forcing client code to change. But of course the method should return a constant (ideally an enum item, as Olivier suggests)